# When can a Box2D/Farseer contact have FixtureA and FixtureB as null?

Tags: c#, c++, box2d, physics, farseer

As in question. I have my contact with `FixtureA` and `FixtureB` as `null`, even though the fixtures exist in the Box2D world.

Comment: Never. A contact is between two fixtures by definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least in Farseer, that's what I found out. When you keep an object of `Contact` and the separation comes, the fixtures on this object will be nulled.